# Rails Active Record inner join not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 models: `Runners`, `Jobs`, and `Surveys`. The `Runner` model `has_many` jobs. The `Job` model `has_one` `Survey`. I am trying to get all the Surveys for a Runner (all of the surveys that are associated with jobs that belong to a particular runner).

Here are my models

runner.rb

```
class Runner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :runner
  has_one :survey
end
```

survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :service, :speed, :suggestion, :job_id
  belongs_to :job
end
```

In order to get all the jobs for a runner I opened up rails console and tried running a command like this.

```
runner = Runner.first
joined_table = Job.joins(:survey)
joined_table.where(runner_id: runner.id)
```

This looks like it outputs the correct SQL, but whenever I run joined_table, all it does is return back`Job.all`. It doesnt return the joined table of Job and Survey. I also tried the following

```
joined_table = Job.all(:include => :survey)
joined_table = Job.all(:select => '*', :joins => :survey)
joined_table = Job.all(:joins => :assignment, :include => :survey)
```

None of these 3 work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to it:

runner.rb

```
class Runner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :surveys, through: :jobs
end
```

and then

```
runner = Runner.first
runner.surveys
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
Survey.joins(:job).where(jobs: { runner_id: runner.id })
```

This should give you all `Survey` objects which belong to a job that belongs to the runner in question.

Comment: joins will automatically detect the foreign_key if the relation is specified on the models, your whole where is superfluous.

Comment: No it's not; we're joining only on a subset of `jobs`, and we need to specify the subset.

Comment: can't believe I didn't think to give Aguardientico's answer (which is obviously correct)! but I'll leave this here anyway since it's still an example of how to write the join query the OP was trying to do.